# Can someone help troubleshooting EasyGui with me?

Tags: python, python-2.7, easygui

I am trying to install EasyGui on Python 3.3 and I don't see to have it. I had gotten it to work with Python 2.7 but not for 3.3.

I follow the instructions from their website:

---

> Unpack the archive file into a temporary directory
>
> Open a console window and navigate to the temporary directory.
>
> At the command prompt, enter the command:
>
> python  setup.py  install

---

But I keep getting this error when I use the command 'import easygui':

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/pyshell#0/", line 1, in
>
> ```
> import easygui
> ```
>
> ImportError: No module named 'easygui'

Comment: I suppose you installed it with the version of Python you have in your path (2.7), so you need to install it as well for Python 3.3 with `/path/to/python3 setup.py install`.

Comment: No file or directory - from the terminal.

Comment: Well, you have to replace `/path/to/python3` with the real path to your Python interpreter :)

Answer (score 2):

For Python 3 you need to call python3 when installing it, so instead of

```
python setup.py install
```

you must do

```
python3 setup.py install
```

Comment: I love you. A lot. A lot. This took me 6 months to get answered. SIX. Thank you.

Comment: @user2063042: How about upvoting and selecting the answer? That's what you do instead of saying thank you here. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just add "easygui.py" to your site-packages directory. It will work with any editor. I am using Coderunner, and I had the same problem. It took me an hour to figure it out :)

Answer (score 1):

easy. type `pip3 uninstall easygui` then `pip3 install --user easygui`